# SQL Server table groupby by date and value based on latest timestamp

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

Consider table 1 and 2 below and table desired outcome with expected output.

[db fiddle link here with all code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=56d019bb37f58d7d354c22ea1163d003)

**Desired output**

My objective is to filter all entries based on latest `p_date` (2020-05-31 in this case) then `groupby` on `id` and `mon_year` but only select the latest entry based on timestamp.

Finally join both tables and assign `NULL` for value not found in on versus other table (see row 4)

Thank you in advance

This is for SQL Server 2012.

```
-- table 1 spent values, desired values commented 
create table spent
(
    id bigint, 
    mon_year varchar(100), 
    p_date date, 
    timestamp datetime, 
    spent decimal(9,2)
);

insert into spent 
values (12345, 'Oct-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-18 12:16:56', 100.0), --1
       (12345, 'Oct-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-18 12:11:56', 150.0),
       (12345, 'Nov-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-18 12:10:56', 250.0), --2
       (12345, 'Mar-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-18 12:15:56', 10.0),  --3
       (12345, 'Jan-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-18 12:13:56', 5.0), --4
       (12345, 'Mar-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-18 12:12:56', 0.0),
       (12345, 'Oct-20', '2020-04-30', '2020-05-15 08:16:56', 1000.0),
       (12300, 'Mar-20', '2020-04-30', '2020-06-19 12:11:56', 150.0),
       (12300, 'Nov-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-19 12:10:56', 250.0), --5
       (12300, 'Mar-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-18 12:15:56', 10.0), --6
       (12300, 'Mar-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-18 12:12:56', 0.0);

-- table 2 forecast values, desired values commented 
create table forecast
(
    id bigint, 
    mon_year varchar(100), 
    p_date date, 
    timestamp datetime, 
    forecast decimal(9,2)
);

insert into forecast values
(12345, 'Oct-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-18 12:16:56',50.0 ), --1
(12345, 'Oct-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-18 12:11:56', 100.0), 
(12345, 'Nov-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-18 12:10:56',30.0 ), --2
(12345, 'Mar-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-18 12:15:56',40.0 ), --3
(12345, 'Mar-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-18 12:12:56', 0.0),
(12345, 'Oct-20', '2020-04-30', '2020-05-15 08:16:56', 0.0), 
(12300, 'Mar-20', '2020-04-30', '2020-06-19 12:11:56', 100.0), 
(12300, 'Nov-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-19 12:10:56',200.0 ), --5
(12300, 'Mar-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-18 12:15:56', 100.0), --6
(12300, 'Mar-20', '2020-05-31', '2020-06-18 12:12:56', 0.0);

-- desired final table join, values 
create table desired_outcome
(
    id bigint, 
    mon_year varchar(100), 
    p_date date, 
    forecast decimal(9,2), 
    spent decimal(9,2)
);

insert into desired_outcome values
(12345, 'Oct-20', '2020-05-31', 50.0, 100.0 ), --1
(12345, 'Nov-20', '2020-05-31', 30.0, 250.0 ), --2
(12345, 'Mar-20', '2020-05-31', 40.0, 10.0 ), --3
(12345, 'Jan-20', '2020-05-31', NULL, 5.0 ), --4
(12300, 'Nov-20', '2020-05-31', 200.0, 250.0), --5
(12300, 'Mar-20', '2020-05-31', 100.0, 10.0); --6
```

Comment: What have you tried so far, and why didn't it work?

Comment: I've tried to group by on id and p_date and apply a where clause where p_date equals the max(p_date); i'm having issues and falling short on the datetime part  or even the order in which i present my logic.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code runs to common table expressions to get the latest timestamp record per `mon_year` \ `id` combination using a `row_number()` window function and then uses a `full join` to bring them together at the end.  The `full join` is to allow either a spend or a forecast to be there. To get the latest date from both tables, run a variable beforehand to get the max date. Commented code is below:

```
-- Get the maximum date available from either table
declare @max_date date = (
    select
    max(p_date)
    from (
    select distinct
    p_date
    from spent

    union

    select distinct
    p_date
    from forecast
    ) as x
);



with latest_spend as (
        select
        id
        ,mon_year
        ,p_date
        ,spent
        -- The partition by is the grouping you asked for, the order by is to get the latest, and this ranks them newest to oldest
        ,row_number() over (partition by mon_year, id order by [timestamp] desc) as row_no
        from spent
        where p_date = @max_date
    
    )
    , 
    latest_forecast as (
    
    select
        id
        ,mon_year
        ,p_date
        ,forecast
        -- The partition by is the grouping you asked for, the order by is to get the latest, and this ranks them newest to oldest as  the first cte.
        ,row_number() over (partition by mon_year, id order by [timestamp] desc) as row_no
        from forecast
        where p_date = @max_date
    )
    select
        ls.id
        ,ls.mon_year
        ,ls.p_date
        ,lf.forecast
        ,ls.spent
    from latest_spend as ls
    full join latest_forecast as lf on ls.mon_year = lf.mon_year 
        and ls.id = lf.id
        and lf.row_no = 1 -- full join,  so either a spend or a forecast can be present.
    where ls.row_no =1
    order by id desc, mon_year asc;
```

Comment: Thanks!! How would you add `p_date` to always default to the latest max value provided instead of harcoding this (ie '2020-05-31') into the script?

Comment: I have amended the answer to cater for this, by using a variable to evaluate what the maximum date is from either table.